# Simplifying a matrix equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I want to know whether there exist any $Y$ and $Z$ satisfying this matrix equality:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N X_iaa^TX_i^T = Yaa^TZ
$$
where $X_i$'s are matrices with appropriate dimensions and $a$ is a vector with appropriate dimension.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the matrices.

For example, if 
$
a a^t=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has rank $2$, while $Ya a^t Z$ has rank at most $1$. On the other hand, if $a=0$, then you can find such $Y,Z$.

Comment: I edited the question. $A$ is equal to $aa^T$ for some vector $a$.

Comment: I see, so it is not correct generally as you showed one counter-example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Usually not, because the rank of the RHS is at most 1 but the LHS can have higher ranks. In particular, when the underlying field is real, each summand on the LHS is a positive semidefinite matrix of rank $\le1$. Hence the LHS has rank $\le1$ if and only if all vectors $X_ka$ are multiples of some common vector $v$.